# How to differentiate a cancelled request with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

in a `$http` error handler, I need to differentiate a real HTTP error from cancelled requests.

Here is an example:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($http, $q) {
    const vm = this;
  this.errors = [];

  vm.errorHandler = (label) => ((error) => {
    this.errors.push(label + ' : \n\n' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  });


  vm.unResolved = () => {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url : 'https://Idonotexist'
    }).catch(vm.errorHandler('unResolved'));
  }

  vm.cancelled = () => {
  const canceller = $q.defer()
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      timeout: canceller.promise,
      url : 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699'
    }).catch(vm.errorHandler('cancelled'));
    canceller.resolve();
  }

  vm.unsecured = () => {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url : 'http://Idonotexist'
    }).catch(vm.errorHandler('unsecured'))
  }
});
```

In my `errorHandler` function, **I want to differentiate cancelled requests from a real error** (such as "insecured" or "unresolved hosts").

It would be a real pain for me to pass the canceller to the error handler and it won't be able to treat correctly requests cancelled by the browser without an angularjs canceller.

So far, here are the errors I get in my error handler.

Error for non cancelled (host unresolved) request :

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "url": "https://Idonotexist",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

Error for cancelled request :

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "timeout": {
      "$$state": {
        "status": 1,
        "processScheduled": false,
        "pur": true
      }
    },
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

I have a config.timeout that contains the promise but I would like to avoid using it. I would like to treat as cancelled requests requests cancelled by the browser even if no canceller.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtassin/wwaku3pm/2/) with the example.

Is there a way to add a interceptor on cancelled requests to flag then specifically ?

**UPDATE**

This can't be solved angularjs $http code does not separate error than timeout or abort. You can see it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/07849779ba365f371a8caa3b58e23f677cfdc5ad/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L105).

A [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15847) is running about it.

Comment: Is the existence of the `timeout` property not indicator enough that the request was cancelled?

Comment: It could work for request cancelled by angularjs bit not by the browser it-self (on page change by example).